# Wildcard Search PHP

Tags: php, search, wildcard

I dunno really what its called but basically this is what I want to represent this as a string in PHP :

```
<div class="post" id="post-*Any Content*">
```

How could i do this.

edit: sorry for not explaining it very well guys, basically I'm going to be checking to see if a string contains this text, where *any content* is basically anything in the whole wide world, as long as there is  behind.

Like a regex or something maybe.

Comment: Uh? Should explain better what you want, otherwise my answer will be `$var = '<div class="post" id="post-*Any Content*">'`

Comment: alright, added better information.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse HTML.